# Is it possible to specify a pin upon which the data sent over i2c can act?

Tags: c++, i2c

A master will send fan speed values to the slave. The slave will then read the fan speed values and change the speed value for the relevant pwm pin. However I am not sure how I can tell the slave which pin the data is for.  Should I send two packets of data in quick sucsession and then have a loop system wherby the first peice of data out of two is always for specifying the pin? Any help in tackling this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a struct to send multiple things, like this:

```C++
#include <Wire.h>

const byte SLAVE_ADDRESS = 42;

struct t_message
{
  byte pin;
  byte speed;
} message;

void setup ()
{
  Wire.begin ();   // initialize master
}  // end of setup

void loop ()
{
  // set desired parameters
  message.pin = 10;
  message.speed = 50;

  // send the message
  Wire.beginTransmission (SLAVE_ADDRESS);  
  Wire.write ((byte *) &message, sizeof message);
  Wire.endTransmission ();
}  // end of loop
```

---

More information about [I2C - Two-Wire Peripheral Interface - for Arduino](http://www.gammon.com.au/i2c)

---

On that page is mentioned how to [Send and receive any data type](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=10896&reply=8#reply8). This includes structs. Using the code there you could send a struct, and receive a struct.

Comment: Perhaps you should also add the code for the receiver, especially how to extract the struct members

Comment: I've expanded my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In a way, yes.  You are making the assumption that many beginners do, that I2C is only able to send one byte.  That's not the case. You can send many bytes as one single packet with I2C.

Send a single packet consisting of two bytes - the first is the pin number and the second the speed.

Comment: so how could i tell the two bytes apart when sent in a single packet? could you give a short code example?

Comment: You don't need to. They are separate. You just receive one then receive the other.  The first byte you receive is the first one you sent.

Comment: how would the counter system work?

Comment: @TCarr What counter system?

Comment: well the first byte will indicate the pin and the second the fan speed. So how can i differentiate the first byte from the second in a data package?

Comment: You don't! It is already done! The first byte in the packet is the first byte in the packet.  I suggest you ask Wikipedia how I2C works so you can understand what I am saying. Do you have a big L on your left hand and an R on your right hand? No? That's because your left hand is your left hand and you don't get it confused with your right hand because it isn't your right hand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30400/discussion-between-tcarr-and-majenko).

Comment: @TCarr What is there to discuss? You have all the information you need. Now go read.

Comment: The Arduino Tutorial MasterWriter shows you exactly how to do it. https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/MasterWriter You send 2 bytes from the master and the receiver event is called with `howmany` set to 2. You read twice, the first is the pin number the second is the fan speed. It's not rocket surgery.